# In Oracle SQL, can I use a semicolon in a comment?

Tags: sql, oracle

Ran into a problem with some internal tools while running a query of the format:

```
SELECT 
a,
b,
c /** This is an important column; please do not remove **/
FROM table;
```

The error message indicates that the semicolon in the comment is treated as the end of the statement. Is this a limitation of Oracle, or of our internal tools?

Comment: what exactly is the error message?

Comment: Actually, you have an extra comma after the `c` that should not be there. Maybe that's the culprit and not the semi colon, assuming you transcribed the query correctly.

Comment: `c,` should throw missing expression.  Otherwise working fine for me. `Select 
    Owner,
    Table_name,
    Column_Name /* this is an important column; please do not remove */
    from all_tab_cols;`

Comment: Comma was a typo, this was just an example query, not a transcription. Edited.

Comment: As edited, this is a perfectly valid Oracle SQL statement.  If an error is being thrown, I would expect that it is a bug in your tooling.

Comment: I don't about your case specifically but Oracle does have some issues with comments and such. Which tool are you using?
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14357/ch5.htm#i1210024

Comment: This is problem with the tool you are using

Comment: @shawnt00 your link says not to put statement termination characters (such as semicolons) at the end of a line within a comment, but nothing about in the middle of a line (as was the case here).

Comment: Have you tried using a `--` comment or possibly just `/*` instead of `/**` in case that's a special marker for your tools?

Comment: @shawnt00 I have, problem persisted for all comment types; I ended up rephrasing the comment so it's no longer an actual issue, just wanted to confirm whether it was an internal or an external problem.

Answer (score 0):

SQL, PLSQL and SQL*Plus have subtle differences.  With respect to `;`, SQL*Plus does not ignore `;` in comments, see the following:

https://svenweller.wordpress.com/2020/08/25/warning-hidden-traps-comments-in-sqlplus/

This example is given in the above.

```
select 'drop '||object_type||';' 
  from user_objects 
  --where object_type = 'VIEW';
  where object_type = 'TRIGGER';
```

This plausible example occurs because the programmer duplicates the *where* line, comments out the original, and then replaces `VIEW` with `TRIGGER`. In SQL*Plus, `--where object_type = 'VIEW'` is ignored, but the `;` is not. As a result, what follows is what SQL*Plus executes:

```
select 'drop '||object_type||';' 
  from user_objects
```

The remainder, `where object_type = 'TRIGGER';`, generates an error.